# How do I get a value from one dataframe meeting certain conditions from another dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes:

`df1` with columns: `id | date`

and

`df2` with columns: `id| begin_date | end_date | var`

I need to add `var` column to `df1` for conditions:

- `df1['id'] == df2['id']` &
- `df2['begin_date'] <= df1['date'] < df2['end_date']`
- if there are multiple rows in `df2` meeting above conditions so take the **last row**.

Expectet result: `df1` with columns: `id | date | var`.

Thanks for advices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can this do in a single step but your data types need to be consistent before you start comparing.

```
df1['var'] = df1.apply(lambda x: df2.loc[max(df2[(x['id'] == df2['id']) & (df2['begin_date'] == x['date']) & (x['date'] < df2['end_date'])].index), 'var'], axis = 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

as far as i understand your requirement,i think you can do it by two steps.

1.first 
    - merge the two dataframes by id

```
merged_data_frame = pd.merge(df1,df2,how="inner",on=["id"],indicator=True)
```

2.second step

- convert date and begin_date,end_date types to datetime
- filter data by your date condition

  ```
  merged_data_frame["date"] = pd.to_datetime(merged_data_frame["date"])
  merged_data_frame["begin_date"] = pd.to_datetime(merged_data_frame["begin_date"])
  merged_data_frame["end_date"] = pd.to_datetime(merged_data_frame["end_date"])
  merged_data_frame = merged_data_frame[merged_data_frame.begin_date <= merged_data_frame.date]
  merged_data_frame = merged_data_frame[merged_data_frame.date >  merged_data_frame.end_date]
  out=merged_data_frame.drop_duplicates(subset=["id"], keep='last')
  ```

Comment: Actually you can you execute your three last sentences into one: merged_data_frame = merged_data_frame[(merged_data_frame.begin_date <= merged_data_frame.date) & (merged_data_frame.date) >  merged_data_frame.end_date].tail(1)